# Mac Pro 2,1 Only Shows Flashing Question Mark After Update

Tags: startup, mac-pro

So, I have an older Mac Pro 2,1 that I received.  Had a fresh install of Mavericks and nothing else.  It worked fine, with exception to slow redraw speeds on the screen.  When I got it plugged into a network for the first time, it said there were updates, so I let it do the updates.

When I returned to the machine, it was simply sitting at a white screen.  After waiting several hours with no change, I turned the machine off, and rebooted.  I was met with the flashing question mark on a folder icon.

The Mac has the Apple RAID card in it, and 4 1TB drives.

Pressing *any* of the startup commands during boot does nothing; I still get the flashing icon.  <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> doesn't work.  <kbd>C</kbd> doesn't work.  The only two that do anything is <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> (reset NVRAM) and <kbd>Option</kbd> (Startup Disc select).  However, even when using those two, they still result in a flashing question mark icon.

Any clues?  I'm wondering if the RAID card went bad or something.  It was complaining of a bad battery.

Answer (score 1):

A flashing question mark means it can't find system software, however, it is able to find the boot volume.  If the boot volume is on the RAID array, then it's not the RAID card.

Try booting from installation media to see if you can see the drive.  If you can see the volume and mount it, you can recover your data.

As for the RAID battery, it keeps the last last set of write commands in the controllers memory in case there is a power failure.  I would replace it because you lose that safety net if the battery has no charge, but it's not the cause of your issue.

Comment: Trying to boot from both an install DVD and from a bootable USB results in the same flashing question mark, even after I select the media from the Startup Disk options (holding Option on boot).  This is the part that **really** confuses me.

Comment: Just to be clear, you *see* it in the boot mgr, but upon selecting it, it goes to flashing "?" mark?  Try removing the RAID card to see if it's more than just the battery.

Comment: Yes, that is absolutely correct.  I will pull the RAID card and see how things go.  Wasn't sure if trying to boot without the RAID card would be a bad thing.

Comment: Not at all, the RAID volume won't be there.  It *shouldn't* be the RAID card, but those are some weird symptoms.

Comment: Welp, I tried it.  As expected, the RAID volume wasn't there, but it did see the bootable USB.  However, when I choose that, I'm met with just a white screen.  This is damned peculiar.

Comment: I wouldn't expect a 2,1 to be able to boot from USB. I have never got a 3,1 to do it; yet the same key will boot both a 4,1 or 5,1.  [Though I have heard people say they've been successful, they either didn't tell me their method, or I couldn't repro it] I'd say DVD will be your go-to.

Comment: Do you have the original install CD/DVDs?  Try booting into [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).

Comment: I don't, but I have some old Tiger DVDs.  I will give those a try.

Comment: So, I booted the machine, while holding D to get to the Apple Hardware Test, and I just got the flashing question mark icon.  The DVD spun, and it seemed like the machine was trying to read it, but... flashing icon.

Comment: That's a new one.  You have the same symptoms on the RAID array ***and*** the SATA DVD, so I am willing to rule out it's a drive issue.  My next step would be to check out the memory.  Try removing all but one stick and see what happens.  If it happens again, swap that stick/slot out with another

Comment: Nope.  Pulled the RAM modules, and ran them all one by one.  No change.  I'm beginning to wonder if it's not the mobo... but I would think that would be giving other signs...

Comment: I agree...it should be giving other signs and this particular sign makes no sense.  For grins and giggles, have you tried verbose mode?  Hold cmd-v while booting (you don't have to old Opt since I will find the DVD)

Comment: Nope.  Cmd-V is one of those commands that this machine isn't responding to.  I just tried it again, to be sure, but no, it's not responding to that.  Holding Option and holding Cmd-Opt-P-R are the only two commands that have shown any response.

Comment: Total guess....Safe Mode?  (hold shift)

Comment: Nope.  Just tried it again, and got the flashing icon.  Shift did nothing.

Comment: Sorry...but I am at a loss at this point.  could be CPU or main board.  Only other thing I would try is removing any extra GPUs you may have on board (and swapping them)

Comment: Yeah, I'm right there with you.  Only one GPU, so nothing to switch with.  I'm on the verge of just hunting down a functional main board on Ebay, and swapping those out.